# can we change the template of live tiles in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I need to customize the live tiles in windows phone 8. I need to edit its template according to my requirement. I need to put image and text on live tile according to my requirement. But I am not getting how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft gives no room for customization in windows phone live tile. We need to use one of 3 provided templates: Flip Tile Template, Cycle Tile Template, or Iconic Tile Template. Each of them provides space where we can put image and text, but we can't alter the layout.

Possible, but not very convenient workaround is to put all customization in the image. Then you can use that image as background image for Flip Tile. If you don't provide anything for backside of the Tile, it won't flip, hence showing only your customized image.

Reference : http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Live_Tile_Templates_in_Windows_Phone_8